# Connecting to a web service on EC2 AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a web service api running on an EC2 instance on aws. We want to connect to it from external applications managed by us, eg iphone app, other frontend applications on different servers. I can't get my head around how to authenticate these. Do i add the ip to the EC2 security group, or IAM? and then when making JSON requests do i need to send the AWS access keys? are these sent in the headers? So say a sample call would be:

> API.post("http://awsserver.com/app_api/v1/request", query: {
>   customer_name: "John Doe", customer_email: "test@test.com" }, headers:
>   {"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"=>"exampletoken", "AWS_SECRET_KEY" =>
>   "secretexample"})

I have tried searching but surprisingly not a lot found. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of, do not send your access key and secret with any POST ever in plain text. The access key and secret key are used to generate unique tokens that expire to access AWS resources at your account level, not your application (API).

There are lots of assumptions I am making, however you will need to have the authentication done at your application level if you intend to have this API accessible from mobile devices as they will have changing IP's.

Look into OAuth where devices request access from some authentication mechanism in your application which will return a token you can send along in subsequent POST requests in the header.

For servers accessing your API you could certainly add those EC2 instance IP's to a security group opening access to your API server and deny all other IP's access, however keep in mind if the EC2 instances do not have Elastic IP's then on any restart they will have a different IP and need to be added to your security group.